# Inner Join doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have tried everything and nothing is working. I have two tables.  The parent table with the primary key and index is childcareinfo and the key is ChildcareID.  The child table is users with the primary key of UserID and the foreign key of ChildcareID.  The website is set to follow the user through the site using the MM_Username session variable.  I have created the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM childcareinfo INNER JOIN users
 ON childcareinfo.ChildcareID = users.ChildcareID
```

but the query pulls all the childcares and not just the childcare associated with the user.  And then displays the information for the first record in the childcareinfo table and not the associated childcare.  I researched and tried the query listed below, but I am told there is a syntax error.

```
SELECT *
FROM 'users' JOIN 'childcareinfo'
ON 'childcareinfo'.'ChildcareID' = 'users'.'ChildcareID'
Where 'users'.UserName' = $_SESSION[user]'
```

Thank you so much in advance.  This has been the only stop in this website and has been ongoing for three long weeks.  I need help to jump this hurdle.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your second query this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM users JOIN childcareinfo
ON childcareinfo.ChildcareID = users.ChildcareID
Where users.UserName = "$_SESSION['user']"
```

anyway note that you had a typo here:

```
Where 'users'.UserName' = $_SESSION[user]'
```

you should have written:

```
Where 'users'.'UserName' = "$_SESSION['user']"
```

Actually you should use ' or " to wrap strings that you pass to the database and not table/column names. Also in arrays (like $_SESSION) if you reference a key in an associative array you need to wrap it with ''. Only indexes can be put without.

Last but not least you are doing a MYSQL query that is indipendent from the tool you use to access mysql (PHPMYADMIN) or the IDE you write your code in (DREAMWEAVER)

Comment: Thank you.  When I press test it shows no data.  Is this because I need to upload the page and have a user logged in.  Again thank you for the help, I have been so defeated.

Comment: @Pamela you need to make sure that `$_SESSION['user']` value is set before you run the query.

Comment: I applied the new query however this line appeared when I upload the page and logged into the website

Comment: @Pamela I can't see the feedback. Btw show in the question the code you use to run the query please

Comment: Can I email you or are you able to email my as I am having trouble coping the code.  I just know that I have a lot of peoples jobs relying on me figuring this out and I am very stuck.  I would like to show you the code page but it says that there are too many characters.

Comment: done.  Please let me know if you receive the email okay.  I assume that com came after the dot.

Comment: no, after the [dot] comes "it" since it is an italian domain ;)